# Vector mechanics in polar coordinates point in water

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, classical-mechanics

[image]

**The problem:**
We need to find the vector $\vec{v_2}$ and $\vec{v_1}$ in polar coordinates.

How to find the acceleration if $\vec{v_1}$ is the speed of water in which the point P is traveling with vector $\vec{v_2}$. We know that $|\vec{v_2}| = v_2$ and $|\vec{v_1}| = v_1$

**My try:**

$\vec{v_2} = -(\phi \vec{e_{\phi}} + v_2\vec{e_r})$

Where $\vec{e_\phi}$ and $\vec{e_r}$ are basis unit vectors.
$\vec{v_1} = \frac{\pi}{2}\vec{e_{\phi}} + v_1\vec{e_r} $

Is it correct?

**We also** need to show how to get acceleration. So how to find the acceleration if $\vec{v_1}$ is the speed of water in which the point P is traveling with vector $\vec{v_2}$. I don't know how to do that. But if I would guess it would be $\frac{d(\vec{v_1} + \vec{v_2})}{dt}$.

How to do it?

Comment: If all velocities are constant, as they appear to be in this problem (no mention of any velocity change as time passes), there is no acceleration.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely (except by wild coincidence) that the correct answer to a question like this will ever involve a term like $\phi \vec e_\phi$. What were you taught about converting vectors to polar coordinates? It would help if you said a little more about that in the question (maybe study your notes first!). We don't know exactly where your misconception comes from.

Comment: The question [How to write velocity in polar coordinate system](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4585432/139123) stated some essential parts of the problem that are missing from your problem statement. I suggest you compare your version of the problem statement with that version (and with the original problem statement you received). In particular, you have completely neglected essential facts about the vector $\vec v_2.$

Comment: By the way, this is an interesting problem in vector analysis but a bad technique for crossing a river. The recommended technique is to paddle in a direction upstream of the desired landing point so that the upstream component of $\vec v_2$ matches the vector $\vec v_1$ and the net velocity is straight across.